# Delayed Compute with Method Chaining in Python

Tags: python

Let say I have a class:

```
class MATH(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.results = [0, 1, 2]

    def add(self, value):
        # Add amount 'value' to every element in the results list

    def minus(self, value):
        # Subtract amount 'value' from every element in the results list

    def compute(self):
        # Perform computation
```

Is there a way to do something like:

```
m = MATH()
m.add(5).minus(2).add(7)  # This would be a lazy and not actually compute
m.compute()  # This would actually run the computations in order
```

How do I do something like this in python?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would have `.add()`, et al, push the operator and the operand onto a list and then have `.compute()` walk through the list, computing the answer as it goes.

Operator chaining is easily accomplished by having each operator `return self` as its final instruction.

For example:

```
class MATH(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.results = [0, 1, 2]
        self.operations = []

    def add(self, value):
        # Add amount 'value' to every element in the results list
        self.operations.append(('+', value))
        return self

    def minus(self, value):
        # Subtract amount 'value' from every element in the results list
        self.operations.append(('-', value))
        return self

    def compute(self):
        results = []
        for x in self.results:
            for op, value in self.operations:
               if op == '+':
                   x += value
               elif op == '-':
                   x -= value
            results.append(x)
        return results

m = MATH()
m.add(5).minus(2).add(7)  # This would be a lazy and not actually compute
print(m.compute())  # This would actually run the computations in order
```

Comment: Because you will always at least have to store the operators and the operands, for anything less than the most intensive computation, the overhead added will likely be greater than simply doing the calculation immediately.

Comment: True, but OP specifically requests that the operation be delayed.

Comment: ..Which is why I'm not inclined to DV anything here, but I think OP should think about if there is another solution that would solve his problem rather than delaying computation. Without more background I can't directly say this is an XY problem, but it does sound like it..

Comment: There could be an XY component to the question, but this is also a perfectly reasonable way to model a symbolic expression: something like `m.add('x').minus(2)`, followed by `m.compute(x=5)`.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, you guys are fast!

Here is another go also with a stack, but manipulating the results-list:

```
class MATH(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.results = [0, 1, 2]
        self.stack = []

    def add(self, value):
        self.stack.append(value)
        return self

    def minus(self, value):
        self.stack.append(-value)
        return self

    def compute(self):
        for s in self.stack:
            for index, _ in enumerate(self.results):
                self.results[index] += s
m = MATH()
m.add(5).minus(2).add(7)  # This would be a lazy and not actually compute
m.compute()  # This would actually run the computations in order
print m.results
```

[10, 11, 12]

Answer (score 0):

As @Rob pointed out, you will need some way to store the operators so that the final `compute` method can be utilized correctly. This solution uses `__add__` and `__sub__`, with a decorator to store the operators. Note, however, that it would be much more efficient to keep a running total of the values that have been pushed to the stack:

```
import operator as op
from collections import deque
def operator(f):
  def wrapper(cls, _):
     cls.operators.append(f.__name__.replace('__', ''))
     return f(cls, _)
  return wrapper

class Math:
  def __init__(self):
    self.stack = []
    self.operators = deque()
  @operator
  def __sub__(self, _val):
    self.stack.append(_val)
    return self
  @operator
  def __add__(self, _val):
    self.stack.append(_val)
    return self
  def compute(self):
    _result = 0 
    while self.stack:
      a, *c = self.stack
      _result = getattr(op, self.operators.popleft())(_result, a)
      self.stack = c
    return _result

m = Math()
m1 = m + 5 - 2 + 7
print([m1.stack, m1.operators])
print(m1.compute())
```

Output:

```
[[5, 2, 7], ['add', 'sub', 'add']]
10
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a string-based approach which requires little brainpower.

```
class Math:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = '0'

    @staticmethod
    def wrap(expr):
        return '(' + expr + ')'

    def _op(self, other, op):
        self.stack = ' '.join([Math.wrap(self.stack), op, str(other)])

    def add(self, other):
        self._op(other, '+')
        return self

    def mul(self, other):
        self._op(other, '*')
        return self

    def compute(self):
        return eval(self.stack)

m = Math()
print(m.add(2).mul(3).compute())
```